# Max distance through BFS implementation?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I realize you can find the diameter or the max distance of a undirected unweighted graph by using BFS twice, my question is about the specifics of this algorithm.

If I were to implement this would I literally just do BFS twice and it would return the max distance? or do I have to set throughout the BFS algorithm the distance and weight values for each node and calculate if the new max is greater than the old max, etc? Because I have heard if you use BFS then the last visited value will be the max distance from your original node, which means I wouldn't need to do all that stuff, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the first sentence is false.

Comment: Is it? maybe I'm comprehending it wrong, the site I learned this from said this "We can find longest path using two BFSs. The idea is based on the following fact: If we start BFS from any node x and find a node with the longest distance from x, it must be an end point of the longest path. It can be proved using contradiction. So our algorithm reduces to simple two BFSs. First BFS to find an end point of the longest path and second BFS from this end point to find the actual longest path."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run BFS *n* times, once from each node. Distances must be calculated from scratch every time: distances from some node *u* have no sense when you run bfs from some other node *v*, so you have to recalculate them entirely.

Now, for each node *v* you store the maximum distance to any other node. The diameter of the graph is maximum of these maximums.

However, as I understood from your comment, you are solving the problem on for a *tree* rather than a general graph. In case of the tree, it is simpler. Run BFS from any node *v*. Find any of the farthest nodes from *v*; let it be *d1*. Now run BFS again from node *d1* and find any of the farthest nodes from it; let it be *d2*. Then, a path from *d1* to *d2* is a diameter of the tree (one of them). There is a proof in the answer to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22855/54567) question.

Note that these two BFS's still compute all distances from scratch. So yes, you just have to run BFS twice.

Comment: So for a graph I would do BFS for every node and then the largest distance would be the diameter?